# Are migrated questions affecting my history?

Tags: support, questions, post-ban

Recently, I got unable to ask new questions in StackOverflow. I understand that I should not appeal this is meta, but what I want to know is that why my migrated questions affect my questions' history.

Look at these two migrated questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889781/how-to-use-input-system-packages-split-screen) and [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75853988/physical-motions-are-not-smooth-despite-high-fps). What happened to these questions is that I mentioned them in a meta post. Then, thanks to the meta effect from -1 they reached much lower votes. After asking for the reason, I got that some questions that **are** related to Unity but not its programming is better not to be asked here. So I myself flagged them & suggested migrating them to the *Game Development* site & they got upvoted immediately after doing that.

I believe that asking Unity-related questions is very on-the-edge & risky & some of them can't be *quite* judged as to whether they're suitable for this site or game dev. Also, a lot of questions about Unity were asked & still are being asked here, so I think that my situation & ban seams a little bit complex.

That's why I don't understand why I've got banned because my other questions, did not receive *awesome* feedback & attention, but I don't think that those questions are enough to ban me, according to [this text](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans#:%7E:text=If%20a%20user%20cannot%20demonstrate%2C%20after%20asking%20a%20reasonable%20number%20of%20questions%2C%20that%20their%20contributions%20are%20making%20the%20site%20better%20(or%20at%20very%20least%2C%20not%20making%20it%20worse)) as well:

> If a user cannot demonstrate, after asking a reasonable number of questions, that their contributions are making the site better (or at very least, not making it worse)

Actually, a noticeable amount of my activity on StackOverflow is answering others' questions & improving them, so I wish to get answers to my questions in this community as well.

Finally, I hope that you understand my situation & at least, disconsider my migrated questions from my questions' history.

Comment: I would assume so, yes. The two questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75853988/?noredirect=1) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75889781?noredirect=1) (these are no redirect links)) have a total score of -7, which *is* going to contribute to your ban. That the questions are migrated shouldn't matter; you still asked off-topic questions on [so], and they weren't well received.

Comment: No. But I'm sure about one thing: META EFFECT did this with me. Those questions have got only one downvote before asking about them here. But anyway, bad questions must be downvoted. I've learned a lot of things from asking those questions, and I think it's not a good idea to wait 6 months for being able to ask again

Comment: @RobertLongson That doesn't say anything about migrated questions.

Comment: You have 4 other non-deleted and non-migrated questions that have a score less than equal to 0. You should focus on improving those and any deleted ones you might have.

Comment: Deleted questions, score <= 0, contributing to the [question ban](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans): [1](//stackoverflow.com/q/75901686) [2](//stackoverflow.com/q/75877062)

Comment: "Finally, I hope that you understand my situation & at least, disconsider my migrated questions from my questions' history." - Your ability to ask a question or your inability to ask a question is handled by an automatic system, and does not allow, anyone to override it.  So the only solution to your situation, is to ask a single question, every 6 months and repeat that process until you have raised the quality of your contributions beyond the threshold where a question ban is necessary.

Comment: Deleted questions that have answers have a higher weightage on the question ban algorithm. Do not delete such questions.

Comment: @SecurityHound It's also possible to provide a (large-ish) amount of well-received answers to get out of the q-ban, though how exactly answers affect the ban is unclear IIRC

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat so do you think that improving 4 questions, ZoeStandsWithUkraine undeleting & improving deleted questions will how much help me get out of this ban? Those questions do not have that many views per day to resolve my problem & get unsigned votes, even if they become the best possible. And even if yes, will I get immediately unbanned or my ban will be shorter or what?

Comment: Do any of you suggest setting a bounty on an unanswered question? Will that be helpful for me to get out of this ban?

Comment: Please improve your questions. You only want to if it gets you out of a ban or shortens it? That seems inconsistent with participating at a site trying to being a collection of good Q&A with volunteer answerers. And with learning towards getting answers for yourself for past or future questions.

Comment: Migrated questions are considered "closed" for the purposes of a ban, as migration is a form of closure.

Comment: @philipxy you're right. But I have a question: Isn't one-way community participation _inconsistent with participating at a site trying to being a collection of good Q&A with volunteer answerers_? I've improved a lot (considering time) of questions & answered them, so isn't it kind of _unfair_ that I can't expect others to do those for me? Or at least, just let me **ask**. You know that I _was_ really eager to participate in StackOverflow and I respected the rules and I respect, otherwise, instead of writing this I have created another account.

Comment: @gparyani I have a question for you: So do you accept that the StackOverflow community is not newcomer-friendly? Because all the moderators that considered downvoting my question were able to **also** flag my questions as off-topic, which is what the site asked them to do. It's better to say that in some cases like this _Moderators do what **they** like, not what actually they're supposed to do_.

Comment: You can't expect any particular volunteer to do any particular action. However I don't understand your comment. "do those"--do what? "ask" for what? Re your initial paragraph's "why my migrated questions affect my questions' history", you acted poorly & closing/migrating doesn't change that. People can argue for different places to draw the line. Wherever it's drawn, people will complain. But the policy is reasonable & needn't be "fair" because you don't have to use the site. Live with how it is & post good feature requests. Granted, SO Inc is really bad at educating users re site protocols.

Comment: _But the policy is reasonable & needn't be "fair" because you don't have to use the site._ This was exactly the answer that I expected from a _Saturated community_ that is unable to manage a huge amount of activity.

Comment: SO Inc owns the site. Users do what we can. You posted bad content, there has to be a line, each user tries to place it reasonably within a SO Inc framework that is reasonable, the site needs the line in that general area in order to exist as a Q&A reference, you crossed it, you were treated fairly. "amount of activity" is irrelevant. [Why are questions no longer being accepted from my account?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans)

Comment: "_I've improved a lot (considering time) of questions & answered them, so isn't it kind of unfair that I can't expect others to do those for me?_" [so] has quite a lot of posts, expecting someone to help you improve your question randomly will probably not work. Your questions so far have not asked about guidance / help on improving your questions, why do you expect to receive the same? Note that such requests for guidance when done well, actually work.

Answer (score 4):

If you ask questions that needs to be migrated then you probably haven't read the [help centre](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) where we explain what is and isn't on topic.

That's OK if you learn from your mistakes but if you keep repeating them, asking multiple off-topic or poor quality questions then you're making work for the rest of us...

- we may have to migrate your questions
- maybe we can't answer them anyway because they are unclear
- maybe we need to edit them into shape

Each question you ask that we look at has an [opportunity cost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opportunity_cost). We're looking at your question that we can't answer or have to migrate instead of looking at someone else's question that we could answer. So maybe they don't get an answer at all because, well life's short and we can only do so much per day.

If you get into the situation where you're question banned the answer isn't to look for everyone else to provide you a way out, it's to take on that responsibility yourself and [edit your existing questions into shape](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/255583/what-can-i-do-when-getting-we-are-no-longer-accepting-questions-answers-from-th).

> **Before you do anything else, fix your existing posts!**

The ban is not just there to stop you from posting, it's there to encourage you to fix your existing posts - because that's really all you can do at that point. If you sidestep that you're really hurting yourself because you'll just get banned again.

When your edited questions start attracting upvotes then a) they are useful and b) for the first time, you're ready to start asking more.

Creating a new account will either result in your account being deleted when moderators find out you've done it to avoid a ban or simply result in that new account being question banned because you've done nothing to learn from your mistakes and when you repeat them again you end up with the same result.

So to answer your question, do migrated posts count towards a question ban? The answer is they ought to because they are your questions and it's your total activity on this site that you are responsible for. That's the evidence we have to determine whether your next question is likely to be useful or not. In reality whether they actually count is unknown because the question ban algorithm is not public. Having said that, focusing on your migrated posts is not a useful activity, which is why this paragraph is right at the end.